# Extracting matches using regex and then passing them into an array

Tags: powershell

```
 $htmltitle1 = "{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up} Tottenham Manager {HEY}"
  $reg = "\{.*?\}"
  $found = $htmltitle1 -match $reg

  $spuntext = @()
  If ($found)
    {    
         ([regex]$reg).matches($htmltitle1)  
    }
```

I can see the $matches (below) but how would I extract each match into the $spuntext array? Lol I've been banging my head with this for hours trying different things.

```
Groups   : {{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}}
Success  : True
Captures : {{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}}
Index    : 0
Length   : 37
Value    : {Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}

Groups   : {{HEY}}
Success  : True
Captures : {{HEY}}
Index    : 56
Length   : 5
Value    : {HEY}

Key   : 0
Value : {Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}
Name  : 0
```

Comment: Obviously I'm a newbie to powershell, but trying to work out the regex classes in powershell and .net is proving to be confusing.  Are there any recommended tutorials for this?  Got a few powershell books but they don't go into much detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
$htmltitle1 = "{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up} Tottenham Manager {HEY}"
$reg = '{.*?}'
$spuntext = $htmltitle1 | Select-String $reg -AllMatches |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Result:

```
PS C:\> $spuntext
{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up}
{HEY}
```

**Edit:** Microsoft simplified property access in PowerShell v3. To make it work in PowerShell v2 you have to split `ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }` into 2 separate loops:

```
$spuntext = $htmltitle1 | Select-String $reg -AllMatches |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Value }
```

or expand the properties:

```
$spuntext = $htmltitle1 | Select-String $reg -AllMatches |
            Select-Object -Expand Matches |
            Select-Object -Expand Value
```

Comment: Hi I've tried your code but nothing seems to get passed into $spuntext. Not sure what I am doing wrong. It's been a long night even struggling to use the code system on Stackoverflow itself.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong. I get an array with 2 items in `$spuntext` when I copy/paste the above code snippet into PowerShell.

Comment: I tried it on a few computers, once I upgraded from v2 to v3 it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's what I get for not testing with older versions. Added a fix for PowerShell v2.

Answer (score 0):

also came up with this after messing around today trying to pick up the syntax in case it helps any other newcomers who were confused like me: (works in v2)

```
$htmltitle1 = "{Quit|Discontinue|Stop|Cease|Give Up} Tottenham Manager {HEY}"
$reg = "{.*?}"
$found = $htmltitle1 -match $reg
$spuntext = @()

If ($found)
  {    
      [regex]::matches($htmltitle1, $reg) | % {$spuntext += $_.Value}

  }



$spuntext
```

Comment: ah, this uses .net class though so Ansgar's is preferred